# How to install trac from python source on a shared host with no admin previllages?

Tags: python

I am trying to install [trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) on my shared host on NameCheap. 
apt-get, pip and easy_install are all disabled on NameCheap shared hosts.

trac python source has an installation wrapper, but I cannot run it since it requires write access to /usr/lib/python/ folder, which my account does not have.

Does anyone know how I can install it in another path?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just unzip the package (libs and modules and all) in a folder, add it to the PYTHONPATH, if you don't control this in the environment then in your scripts:

```
from os import environ as ENV
ENV['PYTHONPATH'].append('path/to/new/lib')
```

and now you should be able to import it. Python is very portable.